# How to configure multiple B2C policies with Microsoft.Identity.Web?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft.identity.web

I want my application to accept signins from two different B2C user flows, using the same tenant and app registration. In other words, I want both of these links to allow me to sign in to my app.

- https://myapp.b2clogin.com/myapp.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?**p=b2c_1_susi**&client_id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-oidc&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
- https://myapp.b2clogin.com/myapp.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?**p=b2c_1_susi_vip**&client_id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-oidc&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

I started with the Visual Studio template for a Blazor server app (though I get the same problem with a basic razor app) with Microsoft identity platform as the authentication type and simply changed the appsettings to put my B2C information.

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
  "Instance": "https://myapp.b2clogin.com",
  "ClientId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", //my client id
  "Domain": "myapp.onmicrosoft.com",
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_susi",
  "TenantId": "11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" //my tenant id
},
"AzureAdB2CVIP": {
  "Instance": "https://myapp.b2clogin.com",
  "ClientId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", //my client id, same as AzureAdB2C
  "Domain": "myapp.onmicrosoft.com",
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_susi_vip",
  "TenantId": "11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" //my tenant id
}
```

Then in Startup.cs in ConfigureServices, I changed the setting name:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

As expected, when I run my app I get redirected to my b2c_1_susi policy to sign in and it connects just fine.
Now I want to add b2c_1_susi_vip. It doesn't need to be the default one but my application should also accept it. After trying several methods I've found, the least broken I got is like this:

```
var auth = services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
auth.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2CVIP"));
auth.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"), cookieScheme: "authvip", openIdConnectScheme: "");
```

It redirects me to b2c_1_susi and at least works with that policy but trying to sign in with b2c_1_susi_vip results in `Error from RemoteAuthentication: IDX10501: Signature validation failed`.

I pretty much always end up with either the signature error or an error about the message.State being null or empty/unable to be read.

Methods I've tried without success

- https://damienbod.com/2022/05/16/using-multiple-azure-b2c-user-flows-from-asp-net-core/
- https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Multiple-Authentication-Schemes
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64525774
- And a few others that mostly say the same as the previous three.

Is this seemingly simple scenario not possible?

Comment: Check the properties and claims configured on both the user flows in Az Portal, especially the 'Token compatibility settings' section for the `iss` claim.

Comment: Both are configured with the same iss claim and return the same value in the token, but the signature is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could get my user flow and my custom policy to work together so I remade my user flow as a custom policy. Then I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67739658) as a starting point for my solution.

1. I created a MyAccountController with a SignUpVip action that's just a copy of Microsoft' signup action, but I set `properties.Items["policy"] = "b2c_1_susi_vip";`
2. In my B2C page template, I added a link to mywebapp.com/MicrosoftIdentity/MyAccount/SignUpVip. This correctly redirects the user to the b2c_1_susi_vip policy with a valid state parameter and sets ASPnet's correlation cookie.
3. I removed the 2nd call to AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp.